# How and when should I create custom data fields?

Tags: contacts, custom-fields, groups, tags

I need at least 50 different "categories" or "custom fields". Everything from Contact Info like Name, Address, etc. to specific information that I would have to uniquely name. I am getting extremely confused on how to do any of it. Is there a tutorial on here, or something? I am really new at this.

Comment: Civi has core fields for Name and Address, so it would help if you explained why you don't want to use the core fields for these tasks.

Comment: I apologize, I wasn't very clear. I guess I was just overwhelmed. However my issue is other than the main fields that civi provides, I have several other fields that I would import from a CSV. I have tried setting up these fields so importing would be easy, but nothing I do works. I watched numerous webinars on youtube, with no sucess.

Comment: if you can spell out the steps you took, with a 'title' that focuses on that, i would expect someone helpful would come along. eg if you go to Customise > Custom Fields and add a field, what is the outcome that happens and what is it that you want to happen. HTH

Answer (score 11):

Welcome to Civi! A great place to start is this wiki post about Groups vs Tags vs Custom Fields:

http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/86213742

There are also sections of the Civi book that might help:

http://book.civicrm.org/user/organising-your-data/groups-and-tags/

http://book.civicrm.org/user/organising-your-data/custom-fields/

Comment: @erinefree you're very welcome.

Comment: @erinefree please do mark this as the best answer if you think it is the most useful one [=

Answer (score 1):

Under your 'Administer' menu there's a 'Customize data and screens' and then a "custom fields" option. There you can add all the fields that you need.

Comment: See my most recent question  please