# How do I find a patch for an issue in CiviCRM's issue tracker (JIRA)?

Tags: issues

For example, issue [CRM-17493](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17493) shows that it is fixed in 4.6.11.

How do I find the patch to fix this specific issue from JIRA?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "checkbox errors"? I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17493

Comment: PLEASE STOP VOTING THIS DOWN! It was a simple question.

Comment: On the plus side @erinefree, If you delete your post now that it's voted down a lot, you get the Peer Pressure badge! http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure

Comment: I don't even have enough reputation to delete it.

Comment: Oh no!  I just voted up another one of your questions, which should push you over the threshold to do basic things.

Comment: I've rephrased the question so it's generally applicable, hope that's OK! That might cool the heads of those downvoting this? Sanjay's answer should do the trick.

Comment: Looking at other questions you've posted, you might find taking time to *phrase each question as a question* helps get better results on StackExchange. [How to ask](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) has good advice on how to work within this community.

Comment: Eg, [Why do deleted contacts cause errors?](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8429/why-do-deleted-contacts-cause-errors) and [How and when should I create custom data fields?](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8152/how-and-when-should-i-create-custom-data-fields) are good examples of "phrasing as questions", but [multi-value import issue](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8316/multi-value-import-issue) and [checkbox import problems](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8407/checkbox-import-problems) could be rephrased to better fit the site format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That patch is due to be released in CiviCRM 4.6.11 but it hasn't been released yet. 4.6.10 is the latest version of CiviCRM.

You can download the latest version from here: [Download CiviCRM](https://civicrm.org/download/list)

Answer (score 6):

If you click the all tab on the [issue](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17493) - you'll see the link to the [patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/7130)

How to apply a patch: [How do I apply a patch supplied in the issue queue via Git?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4622/how-do-i-apply-a-patch-supplied-in-the-issue-queue-via-git)

Answer (score 3):

This is a little tangential, but there are several options for checking an unreleased patch:

http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Verify+a+bug+fix