# Why do deleted contacts cause errors?

Tags: contacts, contact-view

[image]

I deleted a bunch of contacts because I imported the wrong data pertaining to them. I then imported it again, with the right data and it wouldn't let me because of "duplicate" contacts. However I searched for these duplicates and they do not exist. I am at a lost with what to do. Changing their ID isn't an option here. ALSO do note that when I do an advanced search, I do not have the option to search in trash.

Comment: Apart for the Access contact in trash permission, navigate to **Administer - System settings - Misc (undeleted ...)** and check that you have **Trash and Undelete** enabled, just to double check that is not some kind of bug, if this option is disabled the deleted contacts should be destroyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go in to Adv Search, check the 'search in trash' box, select all your contacts in Trash, and then choose the dropdown option to Permanently Delete. That should help

Comment: I tried to find the 'search in trash' box, and I do not see one.

Comment: for wordpress --

administer > users & permissions > permissions (access control) > wordpress access control > check box for access to deleted contacts.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, they are still inside the recycle bin? CiviCRM doesn't delete them form the database, it just marks them as deleted.

Do "Advanced Search" and check the checkbox for "Search in Trash
(deleted contacts)"... and delete them a second time! :-)

[image: search for deleted contacts]

I had a look into my system! I'm using Drupal, and there is a right (permission in Drupal) called "Access contacts in the trash"!

Comment: please see picture above... I do not have that option that you have.

Comment: Then please check your rights! There is right for "Access contacts in the trash".

Comment: rights == permissions (in Drupal at least)

Comment: sorry for wrong terms! I have my system in german...

Comment: no worries - understood - thought i would just offer a language service ;-)